# Huffman tree: card guessing game

Tags: algorithm, tree, huffman-code

> "Design a strategy that minimizes the expected number of questions
>   asked in the following game [Gar94], #52. You have a deck of cards
>   that consists of one ace of spades, two deuces of spades, three
>   threes, and on up to nine nines, making 45 cards in all. Someone draws
>   a card fromthe shuffleddeck, which you have to identify by asking
>   questions answerable with yes or no."

This is an exercise from Design and Analyisis of algorithms.

What comes to my mind are two ways of solving it:

1. Is it a 9?
   No: is it an 8?
   No: is it a 7? ... and so on.
2. Is the card > 5? 
   No: is the card > 2? ... and so on.

Which is the correct approach?

Any help is welcome.

Edit: I'm supposed to use a greedy method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither of those is the best approach. You can generalize the questions you ask further, to be something like: "Is the chosen card one of 1, 4, 7, or 8?".

To decide which question to ask, you'd build a Huffman tree containing the numbers. Then you'd ask: "Is the chosen card one of the numbers in the left subtree?" If it is, move down to the left subtree and repeat. Otherwise, move to the right subtree and repeat.

Comment: The Huffman codes can be ordered so that the questions are just like #2 in the question.  E.g., "Is x < 7?", yes, then "Is x < 5?", etc.

Comment: @MarkAdler: That's interesting, you're right that it could be done in this case while retaining the optimal result. I'm curious how you saw this: did you analyze this specific case of 9 cards with weights 1-9, or is there some general property of the weights which makes this true?

Comment: It is obvious since the frequencies are in order of card value, so a canonical code naturally orders the symbols.  The general property is that value1 < value2 implies freq1 <= freq2.  (Or freq1 >= freq2.)

There may be cases for which that is not always true that still can be ordered in such a way to permit all branches to bifurcate lesser and greater values.